# Daily count for a metric in Grafana

Tags: grafana, monitoring, aggregation, dashboard

I am emitting metrics in my service.
How do I create a chart that accumulates all the values for the key for a given day, for a week.

For example I emit {keyA: 4} {keyA: 2} in a single day.
The bar for that day should show that keyA had a daily count of 6.

I tried to do it but the results don't seem accurate.
I attached a screen shot of what it should look like (Each bar is 24 hours)

What should the settings be for this?

[image].

[image]

[image]